# What logical fallacy is "if some of my enemies/adversaries affirm my claim then it is correct"?

Tags: fallacies

I apologize if this question has been asked before or if the question is poorly worded.

Consider the following situations:

(1) two religious sects, say X and Y are fiercely adversaries. To convince the believers of the sect X about some claim (say Z), the authorities of the sect X say, even some important individuals or some scholars of the sect Y affirm that Z is correct. **Additional information**: most of the individuals and scholars of the community Y do not support the claim Z.

(2) the governments of two countries, say X and Y are fiercely enemy to each other. To convince the people of the country X about some belief or a conspiracy theory Z, the authorities of the country X say this claim is true because some important officials in the country Y affirm that Z is correct. **Additional information**: most of the official of the country Y do not support the claim Z.

Is there a name or a notion for this type of argument? Any reference is appreciated.

Comment: This sounds like the appeal to authority.  Only the people of power or influence seem to matter and not just the average person matters in sect X.

Comment: This is similar to what courts call [statement against interest](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statement_against_interest): it is not in one's interest to agree with the enemy unless they believe it to be true. It is not fallacious as  corroborating evidence, as long as the content is relevant to the enmity and it is not taken as conclusive. Taking it too far leads to the fallacy of [false/irrelevant authority](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_from_authority#Appeal_to_false_authority).

Comment: There is also "Appeal to Opposition" , as described here : 

https://www.logicallyfallacious.com/logicalfallacies/Fallacy-of-Opposition

But it is a little different in that the conclusion goes against what the opposition said.

Comment: but I think it can also be called "Appeal to Opposition" since the conclusion depends on the fact that X is an opponent, X said Y therefore Z.

Comment: It's an appeal to authority fallacy. It's also very close to the appeal to popularity fallacy.

Comment: I agree with those who place this fallacious  reasoning in the same category as the appeal to authority.

Answer (score 0):

Arranging the statements to get an explicit text, the mainline of the argument can be seen to be schematically the *fallacy from the negative*. The fallacy of **argument from the negative** asserts that the untenability of one position/statement affirms the opposite position/statement: The X authorities are on the opposite side of the Y authorities and argue that the opponents would certainly maintain that W (antithetical to Z) if the X authorities were wrong; however, they maintain that Z, then the X authorities are right.

An example crudely put: Soviet authorities claim that they are *genuinely* leading the country in the communist way, because American authorities maintain that they are communist. If they were not, American authorities would not "offend" them by asserting that.

Given the information, the sideline of the fallacious argument is straightforwardly in the schema of *argument from authority* (*argumentum ab auctoritate*).

Notice that this fallacy resembles *argumentum ad ignorantiam*.

Answer (score 0):

The justification for the argument: X and Y are adversaries. Therefore Y wouldn’t support X’s claim to help X, or to be nice. Y would only support X’s argument if it is true, either out of honesty, or because there is so strong evidence that Y would look stupid if they denied this claim.

There is a logical error in this argument: There is the rule “never interrupt your adversary if they are making mistakes”. So if Y believes X’s claim is false, and if Y believes that X believing the false claim will damage X, then it would be clever to hurt their adversary X by supporting the claim. (So X would be well advised to check their claim carefully).

If we ignore the logic error, and the claim is something that fits in with X’s agenda, then we may reasonably assume that X might not have looked very hard for evidence that the claim is false, and Y would have looked much harder and still couldn’t disprove the claim, so the claim is more likely to be true. But both X’s and Y’s analysis of the problem might be wrong - X and Y believing the claim is true doesn’t necessarily mean it *is* true. Looks like “appeal to authority” to me.